# Error debugging project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem when debugging my project in Visual Studio 2019, when I run the program an error window appears, it is only when I restart my PC that it lets me debug again but I don't want to be restarting all the time. Is there any solution? I would appreciate it.

> One or more errors have occurred. The debug adapter could not be
> started. More information may be available in the Output window.
> Cannot connect to the process at run time. Timeout after 10000 ms
> (reason: Unable to connect to destination: connect ECONNREFUSED
> 127.0.0.1:54826).

Only when I restart my PC, it lets me debug again, but I don't want to have to restart all the time. Is there any solution? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Does this occur only with one project, or with _any_ code project? Try making a new console application; can you debug that consistently?